# Symfony code does not have any connection with my databases and crud

Tags: symfony

My Symfony code does not have any connection with my databases and crud:

```
#[Route('/docent/crudpagina', name: 'app_docent_crud')]
public function crudpagina(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $bijles=$entityManager->getRepository(Bijles::class)->findAll();


    return $this->render('docent/crudpagina.html.twig', [
        'bijlessen' => $bijles,
    ]);
}
#[Route('/docent/crudpagina/edit/{id}', name: 'app_docent_editcrudpagina')]
public function editcrudpagina(string $id, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $bijles=$entityManager->getRepository(Bijles::class)->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(BijlesType::class, $bijles);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $bijles = $form->getData();
        $bijles->setDocent($this->getUser());

        $entityManager->persist($bijles);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_docent_crud');
    }

    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->renderForm('docent/edit.html.twig', [
        'bijlesEdit' => $form,
    ]);
}

#[Route('/docent/crudpagina/delete/{id}', name: 'app_docent_delete', methods: ['GET', 'DELETE'])]
public function delete($id, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, BijlesRepository $bijlesRepository): Response
{
    $removeitem = $entityManager->getRepository(Bijles::class)->find($id);
    $entityManager->remove($removeitem);
    $entityManager->flush();


    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_docent_crud');
}
```

#[Route('/user/profile/password', name: 'edit_password')]
public function userPasswordEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{
$user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser()->getId());
$form = $this->createForm(ResetPasswordType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $currentPassword = $form->get('currentPassword')->getData();
        $plainPassword = $form->get('newPassword')->getData();
            if (!$passwordHasher->isPasswordValid($user, $currentPassword)){
                $form->addError(new FormError('incorrect password'));
            }else {
                $hashedPassword = $passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
                $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
            }
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Wachtwoord is succesvol gewijzigd!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_user');
    }
    return $this->render('user/password_update.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
}

#[Route('/profile/edit', name: 'edit_profile')]
public function userProfileEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
        $user->setEmail($form->get('email')->getData());
        $user->setTel($form->get('tel')->getData());

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Profiel is succesvol aangepast!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit_profile.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user, 'profile_form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

#[Route('/menu/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_item')]
public function delete_item($id, MenuRepository $menuRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $menu_item = $menuRepository->find($id);

    $entityManager->remove($menu_item);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', $menu_item->getName() . ' is succesvol verwijderd van het menu!');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_menu');
}
```

---

$this->addFlash('success', $menu_item->getName() . ' is succesvol verwijderd van het menu!');

#[Route('/docent/maakbijles', name: 'app_docent_bijles')]
public function maakbijles(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
$bijles = new Bijles();
$form = $this->createForm(BijlesType::class, $bijles);
$form->handleRequest($request);
//        $bijles=$entityManager->getRepository(Bijles::class)->findAll();
//dd($bijles);

```
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $bijles->setDocent($this->getUser());
        $entityManager->persist($bijles);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_docent');
    }
    return $this->renderForm('docent/maakbijles.html.twig', [
        'bijlesForm' => $form,
        'bijlessen' => $bijles,
    ]);
}
```

#[Route('/user/profile/password', name: 'edit_password')]
public function userPasswordEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{
$user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser()->getId());
$form = $this->createForm(ResetPasswordType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $currentPassword = $form->get('currentPassword')->getData();
        $plainPassword = $form->get('newPassword')->getData();
            if (!$passwordHasher->isPasswordValid($user, $currentPassword)){
                $form->addError(new FormError('incorrect password'));
            }else {
                $hashedPassword = $passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
                $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
            }
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Wachtwoord is succesvol gewijzigd!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_user');
    }
    return $this->render('user/password_update.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
}

#[Route('/user/profile/edit', name: 'edit_profile')]
public function userProfileEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $user->setEmail($form->get('email')->getData());
        $user->setDate($form->get('tel')->getData());

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Profiel is succesvol aangepast!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_user');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit_profile.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user, 'profile_form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: would be great if you could specify more details about the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen your code and you should change the entity maybe if it'
s corrected or your delete it and remake the entity again

also don't forget to add this as edit and delete ;)

```
<a href="{{ path('app_docent_editcrudpagina',{'id':bijles.id} ) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
 <a href="{{ path('app_docent_delete',{'id':bijles.id} ) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i></a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).